# What is the difference between these two return statements?

Tags: python, arrays, max

This is a question from codesignal. I tried the second snippet of code from below and it didn't pass all the tests. But the first snippet did. Why? What's the difference between these two snippets?

Context: Given an array of integers, find the pair of adjacent elements that has the largest product and return that product.

```
def adjacentElementsProduct(inputArray):
    return max([inputArray[i]*inputArray[i+1] for i in range(len(inputArray)-1)])


def adjacentElementsProduct(inputArray):
    for i in range(len(inputArray)-1):
        return max([inputArray[i]*inputArray[i+1]])
```

Comment: The second builds a list of 1 item and then returns that item (it's the max, the min, the anything you want to call it!). The `for` loop only iterates once before you return. The first actually builds a list of multiples of the adjacent values and then returns the max of that list.

Comment: To add to the above response, the `return` statement is executed after the first item in the loop, exiting the function. It never goes on to the rest of the `range`

Comment: G. Anderson - I was editing my post to add what you suggest while you were typing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried these?

The first one returns the max of a list.

The second one returns `inputArray[0]*inputArray[1]`. The loop is never executed to its end.

Comment: Do I change it to `for i in range(len(inputArray)+1:` so that it goes through the entire range?

Comment: The proper way to do it is your first version.

Comment: So there's no way to do it by the second version?

Comment: You can, by doing what the list comprehension does, first create a list and the call max on it. But it doesn't bring anything, it's slower and less readable.